# call console command from controller and read the output in Symfony 2.2

Tags: symfony, console, command, upgrade, symfony-2.2

i faced a problem when upgrade from 2.1 to 2.2

in my action controller i am calling a console command and get the output from the command like this.

```
$input = new ArgvInput(array(
                                'object_id' => $object_id,
                                'client_id' => $client_id,
                                'email_address' => $email
                                )
                           );

    $output = new ConsoleOutput();

    $command = $this->get('mycommand');
    $returnCode = $command->run($input, $output);

    $response = stream_get_contents($output->getStream());
```

it worked in symfony 2.1, but after upgrading to 2.2 first i got the following exception "Not enough arguments.". To prevent this i have added a dummy parameter in front of others.

But after this the command executes, but i cant read the output, it always empty.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

The Symfony 2.4 branch added a BufferedOutput which does exactly what you want.

```
    $input = new ArgvInput(array());
    $output = new BufferedOutput();

    $command = $this->get("command");
    $command->run($input, $output);

    $content = $output->fetch();
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/predakanga/3487705) 
which replaces the ConsoleOutput with the following [MemoryWriter class](https://github.com/predakanga/CronBundle/blob/master/Command/MemoryWriter.php) to solve the problem.

It also suggests using the Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application class to avoid having to create the command as a service:

```
$application = new Application($this->getContainer()->get('kernel'));
$application->setAutoExit(false); 

// The input interface should contain the command name, and whatever arguments the command needs to run      
$input = new ArrayInput(array("doctrine:schema:update"));

// Run the command
$retval = $application->run($input, $output);

var_dump($output->getOutput());
```